The node gyp command throws error when i try to execute it
i am trying to compile with the node-gyp configure build command, because i need to create a conection between my nodejs server and a sybase server, and for that i found the nodejs sybase module "https://github.com/rodhoward/node-sybase/", then when i try to create the jar file that this module using the node-gyp module that i found on "https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp" it throws me this error:
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
gyp info using node@18.12.1 | win32 | x64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.3 found at "C:\Users\maitc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"

gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.9.34728.123) found at:
gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools"
gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
gyp info spawn C:\Users\maitc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\maitc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-f',
gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args 'D:\\Documentos\\Smart Retail Group\\Proyectos\\smartpay-local-micros3700\\node-sybase\\build\\config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\maitc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\maitc\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.12.1\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\maitc\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\18.12.1',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\maitc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\maitc\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\18.12.1\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=D:\\Documentos\\Smart Retail Group\\Proyectos\\smartpay-local-micros3700\\node-sybase',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args 'D:\\Documentos\\Smart Retail Group\\Proyectos\\smartpay-local-micros3700\\node-sybase\\build',
gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: D:\Documentos\Smart Retail Group\Proyectos\smartpay-local-micros3700\node-sybase) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\maitc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:297:18)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\maitc\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Documentos\Smart Retail Group\Proyectos\smartpay-local-micros3700\node-sybase
gyp ERR! node -v v18.12.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok



how can i solve this, thanks for read
How can i solve the error, i need to execute this node-gyp configure build command successfully.
